# Как отсортировать список(List) по частоте повторения элемента

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, list, сортировка

В общем, я новичок в программировании и буду рад если кто-нибудь поможет мне с моей задачей. Задача заключается в том чтоб принять текстовый файл(на английском), например какую-нибудь книгу и разбить текст на слова. Затем программа должна подсчитать каждое вхождение слова и распечатать в System.out все идентифицированные слова и количество их вхождений в определенном порядке: более популярные слова идут первыми.
Решение не должно использовать потоки JAVA.

На данный момент я дошёл до этого момента, но дальше не могу понять, как выполнить подсчёт и сортировку.

```
public static List<String> splitText(String text){
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BreakIterator breakIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    breakIterator.setText(text);
    int lastIndex = breakIterator.first();
    while (BreakIterator.DONE != lastIndex) {
        int firstIndex = lastIndex;
        lastIndex = breakIterator.next();
        if (lastIndex != BreakIterator.DONE && Character.isLetterOrDigit(text.charAt(firstIndex))) {
            words.add(text.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(words);
    return words;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "AG.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            splitText(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если считаются слова и количество их вхождений в текст, то строится карта частот слов `Map<String, Integer>`, а не просто список.  Содержимое карты можно отсортировать при помощи `SortedSet/TreeSet` с кастомизированным компаратором, и затем уже можно проитерировать упорядоченный набор пар "слово-частота" и добавить слова в результирующий список в нужном порядке.

Для вычисления частоты слова стоит использовать метод `Map::merge`.

Использование Stream API не обязательно.

```java
public static List<String> splitText(String text) {
    // 
    Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();
    BreakIterator breakIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    breakIterator.setText(text);
    int lastIndex = breakIterator.first();
    while (BreakIterator.DONE != lastIndex) {
        int firstIndex = lastIndex;
        lastIndex = breakIterator.next();
        if (lastIndex != BreakIterator.DONE && Character.isLetterOrDigit(text.charAt(firstIndex))) {
            String word = text.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);
            words.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    // отсортировать по убыванию частоты а затем в алфавитном порядке
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = new TreeSet<>(
        Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    );
    sorted.addAll(words.entrySet());
    System.out.println(sorted);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : sorted) {
        result.add(e.getKey());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает, буду разбираться, что и как)

Comment: С применением Stream API было бы лаконичнее так как не нужно было запоминать все данные в промежуточных коллекциях

Comment: @DaņiilsPoļakovs, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)